# What is the best technique to develop Layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have been searching this on net and found various answers to this question.

I have been very confused to understand what is the best and standard way to create layouts in android.

Either,

1. Create a Parent Relative layout and put all items in the same
   Layout.

Or

2. Create different relative or linear layout for each item, and a Parent layout that covers all the elements and child layouts.

Kindly guide me which one is the best and industry standard way.

Thanks

Comment: completely dependent on your requirements and the complexity of the layout. no fixed answer.

Comment: it's according to your design needs, thus give your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... so it won't create any problem if i create a Relative layout and put all elements in it ?

Comment: But be aware that more nested layouts more hardcode. but it does not mean it's not preferred. You may do it if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard way. All widgets are tools you can use for your convenience. However, be aware of performance when designing your layouts.

Maybe there is a golden rule:

> The rule when constructing Android layouts is to make the layout shallow and wide rather than narrow and deep.

Please, read carefully [this](http://blog.trifork.com/2015/02/23/basic-android-ui-performance/) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html). Both tell us how to make fast Android layouts.